# jQuery: How to change text button on a <button> tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

Heelo,
I know it seems to be a stupid question, but it makes me crazy

I have some buttons in my page

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><button type="button" id="start" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Start</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="pause" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause" aria-hidden="true"></span> Pause</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="play" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span> Play</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="finish" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eject" aria-hidden="true"></span> Close</button></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to dynamically use jQuery to change one button text; for example I need to change the "Start" text.
I tried the following code without success:

```
$("#start").text = "Open PHASE";
```

Comment: May be you were thinking of `$("#start")[0].textContent = "Open PHASE";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `.text()` is a method. (You can see the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/))

This means that to set the text, you have to pass it a parameter, (the text you want to change it to)

```
$("#start").text("Open PHASE");
```

If you don't pass it anything, like `$("#start").text();`, it will return the current text of the element, which you can store in a variable and use later, like such

```
var text = $("#start").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

`text` is a function, not a property. You need to use:

```
$("#start").text("Open PHASE");
```

For more info see, read the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2).

Answer (score 0):

It's [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) you're after -

```
$("#start").text("Open PHASE");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong its [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$("#start").text("Open PHASE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('#start').on('click', function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).text( txt == 'Start' ? 'Open PHASE' : 'Start' );
});
```

```js
$('#start').on('click', function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).text( txt == 'Start' ? 'Open PHASE' : 'Start' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><button type="button" id="start" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Start</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="pause" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause" aria-hidden="true"></span> Pause</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="play" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span> Play</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="finish" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eject" aria-hidden="true"></span> Close</button></li>
</ul>
```